# Probability of 5 voters

Tags: probability

You are a volunteer for a political campaign; your assignment is to contact voters and urge them to support your candidate. You connect to an app that will randomly sample 5 phone numbers for you to call, from a database with 20 entries. The sampling is without replacement — it would be silly to call the same person twice.

Suppose 16 of the numbers in the database belong to undecided voters, 2 to people who support your opponent, and 2 to people who already support your side. (Ideally you'd contact only undecided voters who might be convinced to join your camp, but the database isn't perfect.)

What's the probability that, of the 5 people you contact, 3 are undecided, 1 supports your candidate and 1 supports your opponent?

I think my solution is not correct but I can't figure out why.

$P(3U, S, O) = 0.8^3*0.1*0.1 = 0.00512$

Another solution I tried was:

$0.25[(5C3) (0.8)^3 (0.2)^2 * (5C1) (0.1) (0.9)^4 * (5C1) (0.1) (0.9)^4] = 0.383$

I multiplied by 0.25 because if we devided the 20 people into 4 groups of fives, there is 0.25 chance we get any of them.

Comment: What’s the total number of possible 5-number samples from the 20 numbers? How many ways could one intentionally construct a set from those 20 such that it includes 3 undecideds, 1 favorable, and 1 unfavorable?

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum thanks I understood the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in Paul's comment, this amounts to a counting exercise. We will calculate the fraction $$\frac{\text{Number of 3U, 1F, 1U arrangements}}{\text{Number of possible 5-member arrangements}}$$
to find the probability in question.

There are ${20 \choose 5}$ possible ways to create a 5-member sample of 20 people. This is our denominator.
There are ${16 \choose 3}$ possible ways to create a 3-member sample of the 16 undecideds, ${2 \choose 1}$ possible ways to create a 1-member sample of the 2 favorables, and ${2 \choose 1}$ possible ways to create a 1-member sample of the 2 unfavorables.

Therefore, the probability will be
$$\frac{{16 \choose 3}{2\choose 1}{2\choose 1}}{20 \choose 5} = \frac{2240}{15504} \approx 14.4\%$$

Comment: thanks for your solution. It makes sense.